# Cambiar dato en DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy trabajando con C# en WPF, consumo los datos desde una api, tengo un datagrid que lleno con datos de usuarios como por ejemplo nombre, correo, telefono, estado pero en estado me entrega 1 si esta activo y 0 si esta desactivado, lo que necestito que en la tabla me muestre la palabra Activo si es 1 y Desactivado si es 0.

asi lleno el datagrid

```
public void ListadoUsuarios()
    {
        List<UsuarioDTO> usuarios = new List<UsuarioDTO>();
        usuarios = GlobalVars.Client.GetAllUsuarios();
        gv_usuarios.ItemsSource = usuarios;
    }
```

Gracias !!

Comment: no existe el DataGridView en WPF, quizas sea el DataGrid, el que mencionas es de winform

Comment: si, toda la razon, me confundi, es un DataGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar una propiedad a la clase `UsuarioDTO` que devuelva este texto que necesitas mostrar, luego bindeas esta a la columna del grid:

```
public class UsuarioDTO{

    //resto propiedades

    public string EstadoDesc
    {
      get { return this.Estado == 0 ? "Desactivado" : "Activo"; }
    }
}
```

Esa propiedad `readonly` es la que vincularías con la columna del `DataGrid` para mostrar el texto correspondiente al estado.

Comment: Gracias funciono perfecto solo cambien el this.Estado = 0 a this.Estado == 0. Gracias Gracias